# What is wrong with this function and conditional statement output?

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

I'm going through a series of tutorials on JavaScript. One of them had me build a BMI calculator in JS, while checking my results. It also provided a solution and explained it out, too. This was it:

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    var bmi = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
    console.log("Your BMI is " + bmi);
    return bmi;
}

var bmi = bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);
console.log(bmi);
```

The idea was that, if I pop in values into the var = bmi line for bmiCalculator, to get an output in the console. It gave me the 65 and 1.8 to try, telling me my output should be 20. Well, it worked (hooray) and I (thought?) I understaood what's happening there.

A subsequent task asked me to modify it so that it incorporated conditional statements and output a sort of "you are under/normal/over-weight" message depending on the calculated BMI. It gives a starting code block of the following:

```
function bmiCalculator (weight, height) {
    return interpretation;
}
```

The problem is that there is no follow-up for this lesson. There isn't a solution (or explanation of it). There's a "check code" option but it just returns errors and I'm not sure what's going wrong.

I had come up with this code block:

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    var bmi = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
    return interpretation;
}

var interpretation = bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);

if (bmi <= 18.5) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you are underweight.");
}
if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you have a normal weight.");
}
if (bmi > 24.9) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you are overweight.");
}
```

It doesn't give me a starting value to use, so I just used the 65 and 1.8 from the previous example. But its errors returned to me include:

```
Your solution is incorrect
bmiCalculator() should return underweight for 6, 2

Expected undefined to equal 'Your BMI is 15, so you are underweight.'.
```

Well, if I put 6,2 in that calculation, I'm not getting 15, I'm getting 2 (I ran it through the original bmiCalculator function as a test. So that doesn't make sense to me.
Additionally, there's another note alongside that message to me:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: bmi
```

I thought that I define bmi within the function, though. Should it be defined in a different way?

Anyway, I'd like to get a solution to this task, since one isn't provided, so I can understand what I am doing incorrectly before proceeding. Would anyone be able to tell me the correct solution, and what I did wrong, so I can learn from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just mixed with variables, should be:

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    var interpretation = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
    return interpretation;
}

var bmi = bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);

if (bmi <= 18.5) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you are underweight.");
}
if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you have a normal weight.");
}
if (bmi > 24.9) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you are overweight.");
}
```

Comment: This looks great! It still returns interpretation (as the starting code had me using) while actually returning the correct and desired result! I see that the two vars just needed to be swapped, and it clicks in my head. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    var bmi = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
    return bmi; //since bmi is the variable where you get the result, so you should return the same variable
}

var interpretation = bmiCalculator(65, 1.8); // here you can store the returned result in any variable, so name "interpretation" will work fine here
// but then you have to use "interpretation" everywhere else subsequently

if (interpretation <= 18.5) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + interpretation + " so you are underweight.");
}
if (interpretation > 18.5 && interpretation <= 24.9) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + interpretation + " so you have a normal weight.");
}
if (interpretation > 24.9) {
    alert("Your BMI is " + interpretation + " so you are overweight.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code block! There's an iteration of bmi that needs to be switched to interpretation in the second if statement, but then it works.  
I was trying to return interpretation as the starting code block suggested, which didn't work...

Comment: @AnghellicKarma, yes I missed to replace `bmi` in the second if statement. I have updated it now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new and learning JavaScript, I will give some suggestions as an answer.

> Expected undefined to equal 'Your BMI is 15, so you are underweight.'.

The code to check for the `interpretation` is outside your function and therefore does not receive a value.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: bmi

The variable `bmi` outside the function is not visible to the function.

Both of these problems are because of a JavaScript concept called [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) which you can read more on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

You returned `interpretation` which is not defined, the following code should solve the problem :

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
  return Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
}

var bmi = bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);

// you can simplify the comparison using else if and else
if (bmi <= 18.5) {
  alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you are underweight.");
} else if (bmi <= 24.9) {
  alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you have a normal weight.");
} else {
  alert("Your BMI is " + bmi + " so you are overweight.");
}
```

Aditionally, you should read the [documentation about JS scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

**Variables declared within a JavaScript function, become LOCAL to the function.** That's why `bmi` is not defined when you do the comparison outside the `bmiCalculator` function

Comment: This is interesting. I had tried to use the starting code bloc, and it seemed like it wanted me to return interpretation. I did think "Hmm, bmi is inside function and maybe that's why it couldn't be read" but I thought that return interpretation would take the value and pass it through to that variable (interpretation) instead. But clearly I messed up!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the tutorial was `The Complete 2022 Web Development Bootcamp` by `Dr. Angela`.
The solution she wanted is below. You did not add the commas(,) and other stuffs. Just copy and paste the below in the tutorial, you will get a positive response. Good luck.

```
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    var bmi = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2));
    if (bmi <= 18.5) {
        return("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are underweight.");
    }
    if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <= 24.9) {
        return("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you have a normal weight.");
    }
    if (bmi > 24.9) {
        return("Your BMI is " + bmi + ", so you are overweight.");
    }
}

bmiCalculator(60, 2);
```